# display angular2 app within asp.net mvc application

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, angular

[Referenced Tutorial](https://hassantariqblog.wordpress.com/2016/10/08/angular2-using-angular2-with-typescript-for-asp-net-mvc-in-visual-studio-2015/)
I am following this tutorial but i wanted to display my angular2 app based on a tab click from the menu rather than have it default load the angular app. so in my mvc i have a menu bar : Home, About, Contact tabs and i would like to load my angular2 app once i click the About tab... How can i configure that?

How can i configure a link in asp.net mvc to route to the angular app? Would i have to change the app/main.ts and the systemjs.config.js file?

Comment: Do you have github repo for that? You can initialize angular application after clicking on About tab. The Easist way is wrap your bootstrap method in a function and call it when you want

Comment: @yurzui i would really appreciate your help on this - here is the repo for the tutorial above: https://github.com/m-hassan-tariq/Angular2UsingASPdotNetMVC

Comment: I don't have time to follow the tutorial. I asked for complete minimal rerpoduction.

Comment: @yurzui i added the github repo

Comment: Did my answer help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Step 1

Open **_Layout.cshtml** and cut angular scripts as follows:

[image]

### Step 2

Then remove

```
<my-app>Loading...</my-app>
```

tag from **Index.cshtml**

[image]

### Step 3

and add it to **About.cshtml**. Also add angular scripts that we have already copied from step1 to `scripts` section:

[image]

That's all. Here is the result

[image]